# Is it faster to access char in string via [] operator or faster to access char in char[] via [] operator?

Tags: c#, string, performance

I have a simple question. I'm working with a gigantic `string` in C# and I'm repeatedly going through it and accessing individual characters via the `[]` operator. Is it faster to turn the `string` into a `char[]` and use the `[]` operator on the `char` array or is my approach faster? Or are they both the same? I want my program to be bleeding edge fast.

Comment: Have you tested this yourself? Do you have any evidence to suggest that the indexing is a significant part of your workload? It seems like you're in a *much* better position to do appropriate testing than we are.

Comment: They are both the same... for any practical purpose

Comment: Why dont you just make two applications. Test both approaches and see which one is fastest ? If the difference is not noticable try to do it like 1000 times.

Answer (score 13):

If you need the *absolute fastest* implementation, then you can drop to `unsafe` and use pointers:

```
string s = ...
int len = s.Length;
fixed (char* ptr = s)
{
   // talk to ptr[0] etc; DO NOT go outside of ptr[0] <---> ptr[len-1]
}
```

that then avoids range checking **but**:

- requires `unsafe`
- you are to blame if you go outside bounds

Comment: I know this is old, but I have a question about this. Would wrapping `s` in a `Span<T>` and using it's index operator be faster than using `string`'s index operator?

Comment: @Andy that is a question best answered via something like benchmarkdotnet - and I suspect it would be contextual: for random access, I would suspect "probably not"; however, if you are going to check each character using `foreach` or a `for(int i = 0 ; i < span.Length ; i++)` loop over the span, then: the JIT bounds eliding for spans may make it faster. It will also depend what framework you're talking about: JIT bounds eliding for spans only applies to .NET Core 3.1 (or possibly 3.0) and above

Answer (score 1):

First of all: you should *measure*. Noone can answer this question definitively without measuring.

In this particular case everything indicates that accessing the `string` directly is better: strings are implemented as arrays of characters in pretty much every language, and converting the string to a `char[]` manually would require an immediate allocation of another *gigantic* amount of memory. That can't be good.

But I wouldn't event take my own word for it. *Measure*.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious drawback to converting a `string` to `char[]` is the need to copy: since strings in C# are *immutable* while arrays are *mutable*, your code would end up duplicating your gigantic string in its entirety! This will almost certainly dwarf the potential speed gains, if any, to be had after the conversion.

Comment: In 2021 this is not the case anymore, we have `ReadOnlySpan<char>`.

Answer (score -3):

`string` *is* a `char[]` array under the hood. So there is literally no difference.

The bigger problem here is that trying to optimize this far down in the stack is probably wasted time, there are probably better improvements to be made elsewhere.

Comment: actually, no it isn't; it is a `char*` *to itself*, and itself has variable size.

Comment: and secondly, there's a difference between array access (`ldelem*`) and indexer access (`callvirt`) - the C# syntax is the same, but they are different implementations.

Comment: Also note that if the indexer was the same for both then you'd need to go through the effort of copying the string to turn it into a char array, which has a cost.  The `char[]` would need to be noticeably faster for it to be a net gain.

Comment: Interesting. Learn something new every day!

Comment: There are only two types in .NET that have variable size (per-instance, I mean - it doesn't change once allocated): arrays and `String` (edit: and `Utf8String` in .NET 5)